# Verify if a value is included between two numbers

Tags: php

I am working with PHP and I want to verify if a specific number is between 2 numbers and if it returns `TRUE` then we display a message

```
if($number is between $value1 and $value2){
   echo 'Ok'; 
}else{
    echo 'not Ok';
}
```

PS: `$number` can be `$value1` or `$value2`

Comment: if($number > $value1 && $number < $value2){

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way

```
if($number >= $value1 && $number <= $value2){ 
   echo 'Ok'; 
}else{
    echo 'not Ok';
}
```

**Logic** : 
So basically if a number is greater than a value and lesser than another value, it is considered to be in between the two.

Hope it helps !

Comment: exactly, and Note the `PS: $number can be $value1 or $value2` from **OP** mentioned.

Comment: Note: If you want it to be inclusive then change the oparators to `>=` and `<=`.

Comment: @FrayneKonok   Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @Poria My comment was a note to the *questioner*. Your answer is fine! Stop changing it. You can add it to the answer, to make it even better.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Yes I got that a second late

Answer (score 4):

```
function isBetween($number, $value1, $value2) {
    return $number >= $value1 && $number <= $value2;
}

. . . .

if(isBetween(1, 0.5, 2.5))
   echo "Ok";
else 
   echo "Not Ok";
```

Pretty self-explanatory

Answer (score 0):

```
$number = 10;
$min_value = 5;
$max_value = 15;

// if $min_value <= $number <= $max_value    
if( min( max($number, $min_value), $max_value) === $number ) {
    // Value is between range
}
```

Though this might be the slowest solution, it can be useful in some cases. [Here is little](http://www.tehplayground.com/#gvCE9uzFa) comparison against other methods.